# Checkbox value set with jquery not showing in POST

Tags: jquery, html

I've been looking for over an hour on the net, nothing showed up. I got some simple checkboxes, with a litle trick to style them, the classic hidden attribute and the label with the style. Nothing fancy.
All I want is to send those checkboxes values/checked status through POST for proccesing.
The problem is that whenever I change those values with jQuery, onClick, the inspector showes the changes, but in POST the input is not there anymore.
I've tried setting the "checked" attribute with $.prop(). It worked for the inspector, but didn't worked on POST.
Then I've changed to using values, setting all checkboxes as "checked" and changing the values with jQuery from 1 to 0 and back.
The inspector showes the values changing, but the POST shows nothing.

Here the HTML form :

```
<form action="./ajax/process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="admEmailParameteres1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="procesare" value="adm-process-parameters">

                    <input type="checkbox" id="sendConfEmailToClient" name="sendConfEmailToClient" value="<?= ($options['email_conf'] == 1 ? 1:0) ?>" class="hidden" checked>
                    <label for="sendConfEmailToClient" class="as-link tip label" onClick="toggleCheckSimple(this)" title="Trimite email de confirmare catre client la plasarea comenzii."><i class="fa fa-check label-check <?= ($options['email_conf'] == 1 ? 'active':'') ?>"></i> Client - email de confirmare la plasarea comenzii</label><br>

                    <input type="checkbox" id="sendAdvConfEmailToClient" name="sendAdvConfEmailToClient" value="<?= ($options['email_conf_sumar'] == 1 ? 1:0) ?>" class="hidden" checked>
                    <label for="sendAdvConfEmailToClient" class="as-link tip label" onClick="toggleCheckSimple(this)" title="Adauga si sumarul comenzii la email-ul de confirmare, trimis catre client la plasarea comenzii."><i class="fa fa-check label-check <?= ($options['email_conf_sumar'] == 1 ? 'active':'') ?>"></i> Client - adauga sumarul la email, la plasarea comenzii</label><br>


                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success mb-5 " value="Salveaza modificarile" data-form="admEmailParameteres">
                </form>
```

Here's the JS code:

```
function toggleCheckSimple(el){
$(el).find('.label-check').toggleClass('active');
var trg = $(el).attr('for');
if($('#'+trg).val() == 1){
    $('input[name="'+trg+'"]').val(0);
}else{
    $('input[name="'+trg+'"]').val(1);
}
```

}

And in the PHP side, if I call:

```
echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST);
        echo '</pre>';
```

The checkboxes are not there if they were changed with jQuery. If you don't touch them, they are there. Extremely strange adn upseting for me, as I am not a beginer. Can't figure this out.

Comment: Inspect those checkboxes and verify value set or not

Comment: The values are set, you can see it in the code inspector.

Comment: I'm confused why you have your if/else logic in your toggle.  The `for` on the label will cause clicking the label to act like they clicked the checkbox itself, so there should already be a toggle going on with the checkbox.

Comment: Taplar, you may have something there. Hold on a sec.

Comment: Taplar you made my day. I have no Idea why I used that if/else in there, but that was causing the whole mainheim. Thank you. Post it as an answer, please.

Comment: You don't have for attr to your input check box element it is for label, seems problem in getting attr value in your code

Comment: I've copied the code from another script I made, for another project, and I wasn't paying attention to the fact that I was double modifing the checked attribute, one with the "for" attr on the "label" tag, and once with the jQuery script. Rookie mistake, happens from time to time.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<label for="myId"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myId">
```

When you give a label the id of another element as it's `for` attribute, then if the user clicks on that label, it will act as if the user clicked on the other element.  In this way you can make clicking a label toggle checkboxes, select radio buttons, or give focus to an associated text field.  Making this logic a part of a javascript method is unnecessary.

Ref. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox always needs a value in the html. But this value will only send to php if you check the checkbox. So remove `<?= ($options['email_conf'] == 1 ? 1:0) ?>` from your code, and set the `checked` attribute only when $options['email_conf'] == 1.

This will be your code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sendConfEmailToClient" name="sendConfEmailToClient" value="1" class="hidden" <?= echo ($options['email_conf'] == 1) ? 'checked' : '';  ?>>
```

Comment: Did this in the first place, it's the logical thing to do, it didn't worked, have no clue why. I'll try it again, maybe I missed something, who knows.

Comment: Ok, now my code is this: 
<input type="checkbox" id="sendConfEmailToClient" name="sendConfEmailToClient" value="1" class="hidden" <?= ($options['email_conf'] == 1 ? 'checked':'') ?>>

The JS code is this :

function toggleCheckSimple(el){
 $(el).find('.label-check').toggleClass('active');
 var trg = $(el).attr('for');
 if($('#'+trg).attr('checked')){
  $('#'+trg).removeAttr('checked');
 }else{
  $('#'+trg).attr('checked', true);
 }
}

Still doesn't show in POST if you click-it. Very strange.